# How to "count" some table cells and print the result?

Tags: tables, conditionals

Thanks to an answer from David Carlisle found on this site I managed to code this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand{\acell}[1]{\gdef\acontent{#1}#1}
\newcommand{\bcell}[1]{\gdef\bcontent{#1}#1}

\def\atest{A}
\def\btest{B}
\def\ctest{C}
\def\dtest{D}
\def\etest{E}
\def\ntest{-}

\newcommand{\zcell}{%
\ifx\acontent\ntest\cellcolor{yellow}0
\else 
\ifx\acontent\atest\ifx\bcontent\atest\cellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\cellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\else
\ifx\acontent\btest\ifx\bcontent\btest\cellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\cellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\else
\ifx\acontent\ctest\ifx\bcontent\ctest\cellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\cellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\else
\ifx\acontent\dtest\ifx\bcontent\dtest\cellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\cellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\else
\ifx\acontent\etest\ifx\bcontent\etest\cellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\cellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi}


\begin{document} 

\section*{Student name}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c}
   Question & Answer               & Correct answer   & Points      &  & Question    &        Answer         & Correct Answer   & Points \\\hline
 \textbf{1} & \acell{A}             & \bcell{E}        & \zcell      &  & \textbf{31} &  \acell{}            &  \bcell{A}       & \zcell  \\
 \textbf{2} & \acell{E}             & \bcell{E}        & \zcell      &  & \textbf{32} &  \acell{}            &  \bcell{B}       & \zcell  \\  
 \textbf{3} & \acell{-}             & \bcell{E}        & \zcell      &  & \textbf{33} &  \acell{}            &  \bcell{D}       & \zcell  \\
            &                      &                  &             &   &             &                      & \textbf{Score}  & \textbf{} \\   
 \end{tabular} 

 Correct answers = ?

 Wrong answers = ?

 Null answers = ?

\end{document}
```

Basically a table where the given answers are compared to the correct answers and a nice colored cell is printed depending on the answer being correct, wrong or null.

What I want to ask is if there is a way to let LaTeX count the yellow, green and red cells and print the numbers somewhere in the document. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I introduce counters which index, based on the color.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{greencount}
\newcounter{redcount}
\newcounter{yellowcount}
\setcounter{greencount}{0}
\setcounter{redcount}{0}
\setcounter{yellowcount}{0}
\newcommand\sellcolor[1]{%
  \cellcolor{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{green}}{\stepcounter{greencount}}%
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{red}}{\stepcounter{redcount}}%
      {\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{yellow}}{\stepcounter{yellowcount}}{}%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\acell}[1]{\gdef\acontent{#1}#1}
\newcommand{\bcell}[1]{\gdef\bcontent{#1}#1}

\def\atest{A}
\def\btest{B}
\def\ctest{C}
\def\dtest{D}
\def\etest{E}
\def\ntest{-}

\newcommand{\zcell}{%
\ifx\acontent\ntest\sellcolor{yellow}0
\else 
\ifx\acontent\atest\ifx\bcontent\atest\sellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\sellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\else
\ifx\acontent\btest\ifx\bcontent\btest\sellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\sellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\else
\ifx\acontent\ctest\ifx\bcontent\ctest\sellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\sellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\else
\ifx\acontent\dtest\ifx\bcontent\dtest\sellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\sellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\else
\ifx\acontent\etest\ifx\bcontent\etest\sellcolor{green}1.5%
                    \else\sellcolor{red}-0.4%
                    \fi
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi}


\begin{document} 

\section*{Student name}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c}
   Question & Answer               & Correct answer   & Points      &  & Question    &        Answer         & Correct Answer   & Points \\\hline
 \textbf{1} & \acell{A}             & \bcell{E}        & \zcell      &  & \textbf{31} &  \acell{}            &  \bcell{A}       & \zcell  \\
 \textbf{2} & \acell{E}             & \bcell{E}        & \zcell      &  & \textbf{32} &  \acell{}            &  \bcell{B}       & \zcell  \\  
 \textbf{3} & \acell{-}             & \bcell{E}        & \zcell      &  & \textbf{33} &  \acell{}            &  \bcell{D}       & \zcell  \\
            &                      &                  &             &   &             &                      & \textbf{Score}  & \textbf{} \\   
 \end{tabular} 

 Correct answers = \thegreencount

 Wrong answers = \theredcount

 Null answers = \theyellowcount

\end{document}
```

Comment: works like a charm